# Swift: what is the difference between using a protocol and generics in a function?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I am trying to understand some concepts of Swift and would like to understand this.

Say I have this protocol:

```
protocol P {}
```

What would be the difference between:

```
func f(_ p: P) { … }
```

And this?

```
func f<T: P>(_p: T) { … }
```

Thank you for your help